# Python silent exit when super().__init__() is not first in order when inheriting pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extend pandas DataFrame with additional attributes so I am writing class (simplified):

*using python 3.8*

```py
import pandas as pd

class ExtendedDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        super().__init__(df)
        self.title = 'some dataframe'
```

This works ok.

**Problem** is if I want to make `super()` not first in order like this:

```py
class ExtendedDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self.title = 'some dataframe'
        super().__init__(df)
```

Then in IPython REPL:

```py
(.venv) C:\project\ ipython -i script.py

[1]: somedf = pd.DataFrame(data)

[2]: extdf = ExtendedDF(df=somedf)

(.venv) C:\project\
```

It doesn't do anything. Only exits without error.

I have **tried** to log:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='D:/MyLog.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

class ExtendedDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        try:
            self.title = 'some dataframe'
            super().__init__(df)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(e)
```

but the log is empty.

EDIT:

regular python REPL give this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m.py", line 30, in <module>
    extdf = ExtendedDF(df=somedf)
  File "m.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.title = 'some dataframe'
  File "C:\project\.venvw\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5166, in __setattr__
    existing = getattr(self, name)
  File "C:\project\.venvw\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5139, in __getattr__
    if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
  File "C:\project\.venvw\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5139, in __getattr__
    if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
  File "C:\project\.venvw\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5139, in __getattr__
    if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
  [Previous line repeated 987 more times]
  File "C:\project\.venvw\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 449, in _info_axis
    return getattr(self, self._info_axis_name)
  File "C:\project\.venvw\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5137, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 62, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__get__
  File "C:\project\.venvw\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5137, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Why it doesn't let me make the `super()` method second in order?

Comment: The function is `__init__` -> `super().__init__(df)` Also the first argument of `def __init__` should be `self` -> `def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):`

Comment: @HenryEcker yes, that's a typo while i was writing question. I corrected it.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but trying to set the `title` attribute before calling `__init__` produces infinite recursion when I run the modified code.

Comment: @chepner, infinite recursion? How did you find that out?

Comment: Nothing special; when I try to call `ExtendedDF`, it pauses for a moment, then I get a stack trace. This is in Python 3.9.

Comment: @chepner, I see, I am using 3.8, no stack trace nothing.

Comment: @chepner are you able to post that stack trace somewhere please, if it's not a problem, so I can have it if I ask on github?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chepner/5b6645a183befb248db3779c1a1027f4

Comment: @chepner, thanks, it's because i was using ipython which seems it doesn't give stack trace. I've corrected now

Comment: This kind of thing is why many languages *force* the superclass constructor call to be the first thing that happens in a subclass constructor. The superclass parts of your object aren't ready before the superclass constructor finishes. The object is in an unsafe state for subclass initialization to begin.

Comment: But Python doesn't have separate "parts" of the object; attributes are attribute, the only difference being whose methods make the assignments. Here, it looks like `Dataclass` makes some weird division of labor between `__new__` and `__init__`. I can see not being able to *use* a particular attribute before `__init__` can actually create it; preventing you from safely *defining* an attribute is a bit odd.

Comment: @chepner: `pandas.DataFrame` just inherits `object.__new__`. It's not doing anything special in `__new__`. Pandas needs to control how attribute assignment works on a dataframe, and if you don't call `__init__`, you don't give Pandas a chance to set up the state `__setattr__` relies on. It's no different than trying to call any other superclass method without performing superclass initialization.

Comment: The fact that attributes are all mixed together in a dict instead of being physically separated into "superclass parts" and "subclass parts" doesn't really matter. The stuff the superclass code relies on isn't initialized.

Comment: I consider anything that breaks something as fundamental as attribute assignment until `__init__` gets called a bug.

Comment: For one, it doesn't play well with multiple inheritance, where you can't guarantee that `Dataframe.__init__` will be the first thing called by `super().__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is trying to figure out if `self.title` is a column of your dataframe, because it needs to handle the assignment differently if `self.title` is a column.

Because you didn't call the superclass constructor, the object is in an unsafe state, which Pandas' attribute handling logic was never designed to deal with. Pandas goes into infinite recursion trying to figure out what columns this uninitialized object has.

This kind of thing is why many languages *force* the superclass constructor call to be the first thing that happens in a subclass constructor. The superclass parts of your object aren't ready before the superclass constructor finishes. The object is in an unsafe state for subclass initialization to begin.

Comment: is there any way around it?

Comment: @cikatomo: Call `super().__init__` first.

Comment: I am already aware of that, thank you, I mean is there anything else?